# How to adjust padding in the footer of the table

Tags: html, css, email, html-email, email-templates

[I wanna create a footer like this using tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0M38F.png) but i ended up in this. If i give padding for "call us" line, the columns created before are also getting affected please provide me a solution. Just help me to enter those last two lines, and if i had committed mistakes in any of the part kindly correct me.

Here is my HTML

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Email Template</title>
</head>
<body style="margin:0 auto;">
 <div class="table-container" style="margin:0 auto; width:700px; height:auto; background-color:#fafafa; font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto; width:650px;">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <td>
      <div style="border-bottom:3px solid #dedede; ">
       <img src="../images/index.png" style="display:block; margin:auto; padding:20px 0 30px;">
      </div>
     </td>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <table style="margin:0 auto; width:530px;">
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="color:#444d54; border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:20px 0; font-size:16px;">
       <span style="color:#444d54; font-size:25px; letter-spacing: 1px;"> 
        You Successfully Signed Up<br>with HelloSells
       </span>
       <p style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold;">
        Hello Michael Payne
       </p>
       <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px;">
        Thanks for signing up with HelloSells!
       </p>
       <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px; line-height:1.5em; padding:20px 0;">   We're excited to start helping you grow your business. Our team is already     on activating your account. We'll contact you shortly to get your 24&Chi;7&Chi;  365 service up and running.
       </p>
       <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px;">
        Here's your billing, service, and profile information.
       </p>
      </td>
     </tr> 
     <!-- Billing info -->
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">BILLING INFORMATION</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Unique Pin</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">838b4e1f-88c6-4840-8438-fbadcf5a7a44</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Company Name</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">test company</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Name</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">Avinash</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Phone</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">9090909090</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Address</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">test</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">City</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">test</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">State</td>
      <td style="color:#555d64;">California</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54;font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Postal Code</td>
      <td style="color:#555d64;">1231</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- YOUR ONLINE PROFILE -->
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">YOUR ONLINE PROFILE</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Email Address</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">nash@hellosells.com</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Account Number</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">883013965</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54;font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Service Plan</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$200/mo</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
     </tr>
     <!-- charges -->
     <tr>
      <td style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">CHARGES</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Service Plan</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$200</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Additional Services</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Account Number</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$0</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Setup Charges</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$49</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Total Charges</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">$249</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Transaction ID</td>
      <td style="color:#646b72;">B70P7B98666B</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
     </tr>
     </tbody>
     <!-- img section-->  
     <tfoot>
      <tr>
       <td style="padding:40px 0 40px;"><img src="../images/logo_footer.png"></td>
       <td style="color:#444d54; padding:40px 0 30px; ">Thank You</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style=""></td>
       <td style="color:#646b72;">Call us at <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#59a3ea;">1.800.461.8520</a> or send an email at: <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#59a3ea;">help@hellosells.com</a> if you have any questions.</td>
      </tr>
     </tfoot>  
  </table>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't find any "call us" line

Comment: dont check the snippet, check the image

Answer (score 1):

Like this, where you change "Thank you" line's bottom padding to 0, `padding: 30px 0 0`

*Updated, added comments in the markup to show what changed, where I added a missing `colspan="2"` and fixed the markup between the 2 tables (made 1 instead of 2)*

*If you want the left column's text to not break line, replace the space with `&nbsp;`*

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Email Template</title>
</head>

<body style="margin:0 auto;">
  <div class="table-container" style="margin:0 auto; width:700px; height:auto; background-color:#fafafa; font-family: Tahoma, sans-serif;">
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:0 auto; width:650px;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <div style="border-bottom:3px solid #dedede; ">
              <img src="../images/index.png" style="display:block; margin:auto; padding:20px 0 30px;">
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <!-- removed the table start tag -->
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="color:#444d54; border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:20px 0; font-size:16px;">
            <span style="color:#444d54; font-size:25px; letter-spacing: 1px;"> 
        You Successfully Signed Up<br>with HelloSells
       </span>
            <p style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold;">
              Hello Michael Payne
            </p>
            <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px;">
              Thanks for signing up with HelloSells!
            </p>
            <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px; line-height:1.5em; padding:20px 0;">We're excited to start helping you grow your business. Our team is already on activating your account. We'll contact you shortly to get your 24&Chi;7&Chi; 365 service up and running.
            </p>
            <p style="color:#646b72; font-size:16px;">
              Here's your billing, service, and profile information.
            </p>
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Billing info -->
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">BILLING INFORMATION</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Unique Pin</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">838b4e1f-88c6-4840-8438-fbadcf5a7a44</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;padding-right: 50px">Company&nbsp;Name</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">test company</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Name</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">Avinash</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Phone</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">9090909090</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Address</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">City</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">test</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">State</td>
          <td style="color:#555d64;">California</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54;font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Postal Code</td>
          <td style="color:#555d64;">1231</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- YOUR ONLINE PROFILE -->
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">YOUR ONLINE PROFILE</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Email Address</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">nash@hellosells.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Account Number</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">883013965</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54;font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Service Plan</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$200/mo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
        </tr>
        <!-- charges -->
        
        <!--  colspan="2" was missing in below td -->
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="letter-spacing:1px; color: #444d54; font-weight:bold; padding:30px 0 30px;">CHARGES</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Service Plan</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Additional Services</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Account Number</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Setup Charges</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$49</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Total Charges</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">$249</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;">Transaction ID</td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">B70P7B98666B</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="2" style="border-bottom:2px solid #dedede; padding:30px 0 0;"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <!-- img section-->
      <tfoot>
        <tr>
          <td style="padding:30px 0 0;">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/50/f00">
          </td>
          <td style="color:#444d54; padding:30px 0 0; ">Thank You</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style=""></td>
          <td style="color:#646b72;">Call us at <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#59a3ea;">1.800.461.8520</a> or send an email at: <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; color:#59a3ea;">help@hellosells.com</a> if you have any questions.</td>
        </tr>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yep exactly, but without affecting the previous columns

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy And how does my answer affect previous columns?

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy So did my answer solved your question?

Comment: nope when i add second line the other columns are getting affected, just go back to my snippet to find this

Comment: guess u have noticed the changes in "profile" and "charges" section

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy Updated answer. That is because they miss `colspan="2"`

Comment: can you pls send the updated snippet.? where to add colspan=2

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy You also have the first table's end tag wrong ... will update you code in a sec.

Comment: dude r u working i m just waiting for your answer.? i need to submit this file within 1 hour.

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy Updated my answer. Now the code has a proper markup

Comment: check the image on the first  line of my question dude! i need to give spacing for charging and online profile sections

Comment: Your snippet doesn't give space in that area

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy Updated again, giving those a top padding of 60px. And as the markup is properly written now, you can change it how you need it

Comment: baskarkalyanasamy@outlook.com just ping me to mail pls, still have the issue, ill send u the original file

Comment: still see i need a space between the left and right td in the charges section

Comment: and the company Name in the billing should come in single line

Comment: @BaskarKalyanasamy Changed this line in my answer to make that happen `<td style="color:#444d54; font-weight:bold; line-height: 2em;padding-right: 50px">Company&nbsp;Name</td>` by adding a padding and the replaced space with `&nbsp;`